# What is the plural of tutoriel?

Tags: pluriel, anglicismes

I am really hesitant toward what is considered as a correct plural for the word *tutoriel*. Are *tutoriels* and *tutoriaux* both correct?

I have come across different sentences using either term. From what I have understood so far, *tutoriels* would be the real French plural for the word, which seems confirmed by the French [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tutoriel). Allegedly *Tutoriaux* comes from the English word *tutorial* and might be considered as an improper usage. I would like to know if both are considered as correct, or if *tutoriaux* is really an error.

Comment: Didacticiels sera mieux compris.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina Les deux mots peuvent parfois être employés à la place l'un de l'autre mais il faut préciser qu'ils ne sont pas forcément synonymes, [didacticiel](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=501639), [tutoriel](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8871107) et que tutoriel ne s'emploie que dans le contexte de l'informatique.

Comment: Nope, tutoriel is better in many cases, especially in I.T. Didactitiel is the 'old' version. Both tutoriels & tutoriaux are right but it sounds more naturel to use tutoriels. In french plural of words that end by 'al/el/elle' is usually the base (called radical) + 'aux/eaux'. Example : un cheval => deux chevaux but there are many exceptions as un carnaval => deux carnavals. Here you can find a (non complete) list of the exceptions http://grammaire.reverso.net/5_5_03_pluriel_des_noms_et_adjectifs_en_al.shtml

Comment: @guillaume girod-vitouchkina Non. L'usage de *didactitiel* en tant que document visant à enseigner une technologie ou une méthode s'est perdu au profit de *tutoriel* ou de *guide*. Didactitiel est tout à fait correct, mais il ne sera pas forcément le mieux adapté, au contraire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Tutoriel* is a new word in French obviously imported from English tutorial because of the internet becoming more and more important in the past decades. Its plural form is *tutoriels*, as expected.

However, for those who consider that *tutorial* would be a French word, I do understand that the plural form *tutoriaux* comes to mind, as for many words ending in "-al". But it is definitely a mistake (at least for now).

Comment: Effectivement la  [Commission générale de terminologie et de néologie](http://bit.ly/2aZQUxD) donne « tutoriel » pour traduire *tutorial* et le [GTD](http://www.gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8871107) considère que *tutorial* est  le terme anglais emprunté intégralement.